# Node Async - Working async method returns undefined inside async.parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined, async.js

Basically I have a method fetching values from an API and works, but inside async.parallel the results listed are all undefined.

Here's the method:

```
function getNumberOfSharesFromFacebookApi(url ,callback) {

  request(facebookApiUrl + url + '&format=json', function (error, response, body) {
    let res = 0;

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      try {
        res = JSON.parse(body)[0]['total_count'];
      } catch(err) { }
    }
    callback(res);
  });
}
```

Here's the async call:

```
async.parallel ([
  callback => {
    getNumberOfSharesFromFacebookApi(urlsToTest[0], callback);
  },
  callback => {
    getNumberOfSharesFromFacebookApi(urlsToTest[1], callback);
  },
  callback => {
    getNumberOfSharesFromFacebookApi(urlsToTest[2], callback);
  },
  callback => {
    getNumberOfSharesFromFacebookApi(urlsToTest[3], callback);
  }
],
(err, results) => { 
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: Async.js expects you to use the node callback convention, wherein the first argument signifies an error. Your `getNumberOfSharesFromFacebookApi` function doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

on your request function, place your response as the 2nd argument of the callback. request uses node style callbacks wherein the 1st argument is an error.

```
 function getNumberOfSharesFromFacebookApi(url ,callback) {
    request(facebookApiUrl + url + '&format=json', function (error, response, body) {
      if(error) return callback(error); //callback on error
      let res = 0;

      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        try {
          res = JSON.parse(body)[0]['total_count'];
        } catch(err) { }
      }
      callback(null, res);
    });
  }
```